# Can't execute the KeyUp and KeyDown events in my WP application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, keypress

Basically, what I am trying to achieve here is that if a 'button' that I have created is pressed, it prints a character on a 'text block' and soon as I release it, it prints another on it. This is a small part of an application that I am building. But, the problem is my events never get executed, it works fine when I use Click event for the button though, but, it doesn't solve the purpose. So, I need some help with this. I read online that I have to set up Control.IsInputKey method but, I am not able to set it up being a newbie. So, please help me through it and I'll be grateful to you for making my work easier. 
This is the code that I am using in this context where 'command' is the name assigned to the TextBlock and 'test' is the name assigned to my Button.

```
 private void test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        command.Text = "Y";
    }

    private void test_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        command.Text = "N";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to deside on which key you want theese events to fire. Your code right now, does nothing since you don't check which key is pressed. To do so you need to do this:

```
private void test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.SomeKey)
       command.Text = "Y";
}

private void test_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == System.Windows.Inpput.Key.SomeKey)
       command.Text = "N";
}
```

Comment: Oh, now I get what a stupid blunder I was doing! By 'key' they mean the keys on the keyboard! Didn't know, sorry! I assumed that it was basically turning that button into a key. Some other way I can achieve this? As it is a phone application so, I apparently have no 'keys'.

Comment: I was able to achieve my desired output by using a polygon instead of a button using 'mouseleftbuttondown' and 'mouseleftbuttonup' events! I don't know if they can be used with buttons though. More or less, it works some way if not exactly that!